# Navigate up by back button with Navigation Component

Tags: android, android-architecture-navigation

I use navigation components to navigate from one fragment to another. However, when the user press the back button, I want to navigate back to first fragment. But it keep showing the second fragment. This is my nav_graph:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/nav_graph"
    app:startDestination="@id/fragment1">
    <fragment
            android:id="@+id/fragment2"
            android:name="com.myapp.ui.fragments.Fragment2"
            android:label="fragment_2" />
    <fragment
            android:id="@+id/fragment1"
            android:name="com.myapp.ui.fragments.Fragment1"
            android:label="fragment_1">

        <action
                android:id="@+id/action_fragment1_to_fragment2"
                app:destination="@id/fragment2"
                app:enterAnim="@anim/fragment_fade_enter"
                app:exitAnim="@anim/fragment_fade_exit"
                app:popUpTo="@id/fragment1" />
    </fragment>
</navigation>
```

And this is how I trigger the navigation in the code of my Fragment1-Class:

```
 viewModel.itemSelected.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) {
        navigate(it)
    }
```

....

```
fun navigate(id: Long){
    val bundle = Bundle()
    bundle.putLong("itemid", id)    
    getNavController().navigate(R.id.action_fragment1_to_fragment2, bundle)
}
```

**Edit:**
Corrected startDestination in XML.

**Edit2:**
Added more code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using a LiveData for an event. LiveData always caches the set value, so when you return to your Fragment1, you observe the LiveData again and get the same value a second time, causing you to navigate() yet again.

See [this blog post](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/livedata-with-snackbar-navigation-and-other-events-the-singleliveevent-case-ac2622673150) for more information and alternatives.

Comment: Thank you, but I already tried this. The result was that the app finished when I add popUpToInclusive.

Comment: Your start destination is `overviewFragment` according to the code you posted, so that should still be on the back stack, right?

Comment: Ah, sorry for the mistake, the start fragment is `fragment1`. I overlooked that when I prepared the xml for SO. I'll correct that in the post.

Comment: Okay, then it seems like you don't want `popUpTo` or `popUpToInclusive` at all. Can you include the surrounding code for where you call `navigate()`? Are you calling this within an `observe` block?

Comment: Yes thats true, I call it in an observe block.

Comment: You are right! Had the live data problem once before, but did not get the missing link to my actual problem. Thank you very much !!